# Can I use php to throw server error with message?

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I throw a error at server.

```
header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
echo 'this is error message';
exit();
```

At the client side, I use android's Volley to send the request and handle the error in `onErrorResponse`

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

But I cannot found any message inside the error variable, how can I send a message to client with error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you can try parse error message if available by using the following:

```
            @Override
            protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
                String json;
                if (volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null) {
                    try {
                        json = new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data,
                                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(volleyError.networkResponse.headers));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        return new VolleyError(e.getMessage());
                    }
                    return new VolleyError(json);
                }
                return volleyError;
            }
```

Hope it helps!