# Volley and receive status line of HTTP response

Tags: android, http, android-volley

I'm trying to use Volley lib for network requests...
The one things that I can't implement.
If the server returns an error it could send not only status code but also status text (this is not a part of response body [http response](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6)).

So the question is how to get this `Reason-Phrase` from VolleyError...


parseNetworkresponse & parseNetworkError doesn't help

```
public class EJSONRequest extends JsonObjectRequest{
public EJSONRequest(int method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener);
}

@Override
protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    Log.v("w201"," --- Network response ---" );
    Log.v("w201",response.toString() );
    Log.v("w201",new String(response.data));
    Log.v("w201"," ------------------------" );
    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
}

@Override
protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
    Log.v("w201", "--- Error --- ");
    Log.v("w201","getMesssage: "+volleyError.getMessage());
    Log.v("w201","status Code: "+volleyError.networkResponse.statusCode);
    Log.v("w201","data: "+new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
    Log.v("w201","--------------" );
    return super.parseNetworkError(volleyError);
}}
```

in log next:

```
--- Error ---
getMesssage: null
status Code: 401
data:
```

But I need to take this string in response:

### [image: server status line]

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280023/can-i-use-php-to-throw-server-error-with-message/34280204#34280204

Comment: No this solution parse network response (body of response) - `this is error message`. But I need to catch `Internal Server Error`

Comment: `parseNetworkError` is different from `parseNetworkResponse`

Comment: About `parseNetworkResponse`, you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33573803/how-to-send-a-post-request-using-volley-with-string-body/33578202#33578202

Comment: Doesn't help (updated my question)